# Form validation with error message using angular ngMessage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select2, ui-select, ng-messages

I am using `ui-select` with some multi select field and I want to implement a client-side `<form>` validation like this :

```
<form name="newProjectForm" ng-submit="p.addProject()" class="inputsContainer" novalidate> 
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : newProjectForm.frameworks.$invalid && 
                                                    !newProjectForm.frameworks.$pristine }">
    <label>Frameworks</label>
  <ui-select name="frameworks" multiple ng-model="p.newProject.frameworks" sortable="true" 
             close-on-select="false" required>
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select framework...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="framework.id as framework in p.frameworksList
                               | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, language: $select.search}">
      <div ng-bind-html="framework.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <small>
        language : <span ng-bind-html="''+framework.language | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
    <div ng-messages="newProjectForm.frameworks.$error">
      <p ng-messages="required">THIS IS REQUIRED</p>
    </div>
    <p ng-show="newProjectForm.frameworks.$invalid && !newProjectForm.frameworks.$pristine" 
       class="help-block">Project frameworks is required.</p>
  </div>
<!-- ... -->
```

So, the problem is that the conditions I tried are not working :

`newProjectForm.frameworks.$invalid && !newProjectForm.frameworks.$pristine">` seems to be always false.

`<div ng-messages="newProjectForm.frameworks.$error">` doesnt seem to work as well.

However, I tested using this line instead :

`<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : true }">`

And it worked, so I'm guessing that's the conditions that are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like `ui-select` and `required` don't work together.

So if you meet the same issue, you can use a custom directive instead of required :

```
app.directive('uiSelectRequired', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.uiSelectRequired = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (modelValue && modelValue.length > 0)
          return true;
        return false;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Then you just need to replace `required` with `ui-select-required` in the HTML view.

Comment: this didn't work for me. modelValue and viewValue are undefined when its containing function is executed